# Syntax error in definition of swap function

Tags: c

```
// swap
#include<stdio.h>
int swap(int, int);
int main(){
    int n = 7, m = 9;
    swap(n,m);
 }

swap (a,b){ // I get error here!
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    printf("%d and %d ", a,b);

 }
```

I am stuck on an error. The error message is:

```
[Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
```

Comment: that is invalid c syntax => `swap(int a, int b)`

Comment: " expected constructor, destructor," --> Looks like using a C++ compiler for C code.  Step 1, use a C compiler.  Step 2 enable all warnings.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to enter return type and parameter types

```
#include<stdio.h>
int swap(int, int);
int main(){
int n = 7, m = 9;
swap(n,m);
}

int swap (int a,int b){ // You forgot return type  and parameter type
int c = a;
a = b;
b = c;
printf("%d and %d ", a,b);

}
```

Since you are a beginner, read The C Programming Languages Second Edition book by Dennis M Ritchie, free pdf may be online :)

Comment: I down-voted for the bad an irrelevant book recommendation. As one example relevant to this question, K&R completely fails to teach that implicit int return type no longer works in C and has not done so for 23 years. A half-decent book would mention it.